# MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my connection file

```
const connectDB = async () =>{
        const conn = await new mongoose("mongodb+srv://nikunj:gadia7420@cluster0.94xph.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        {
            usenewurlparser:true,
            usecreateindex:true,
            usefindmodify:true,
            useunifiedtropology:true,
            urlencoded:true
        })
}
module.exports = connectDB;
```

this is my models file

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    avatar:{
        type:String,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
      type  : String,
     required:true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

this file will insert or take information from database for registeration

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const bcrypt= require('bcrypt');

router.post('/register',async(req,res,next)=>{
    const  {username,email,password}=req.body;
    try{
        let user_exist = await User.findOne({email:email});
        if(user_exist){
            success="false";
            msg="user already exist";
        } else {
            //importing data to models
            let user = new User();
            user.username = username;
            user.email = email ;
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            user.password =  await bcrypt.hash(password,salt),
            user.avatar =  "https://gravatar.com/avatar/?s=200&d=retro"
            await user.save();
            res.json({
                sucess:true,
                user:user,
                msg:"user registered"
            })
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is my main file (server.js )

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const colors = require('colors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
//creating main platform
connectDB;
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
const app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
dotenv.config({
    path:'./config/config.env'
})
app.use(express.json({}))
app.use(express.json({
    extended:true
}))

//creating server
app.use('/api/todo/auth',require('./routes/user'));
const Port = process.env.port;
app.listen(Port,
    console.log(`listening on port :${Port}` .red.underline.bold));
//creating req,res platform
```

but after running this it shows error while giving post request

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\nikunj\Programming\todoapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:20)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
```

pls find a solution for this. thanks .sorry if it is a silly or wrong question because I am new to this nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to your database 1st and after that start your server.

You're trying to query the database without connecting to your database.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering

> Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately, without waiting for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB.

> That's because mongoose buffers model function calls internally. This buffering is convenient, but also a common source of confusion. Mongoose will not throw any errors by default if you use a model without connecting.

---

```
connectDB()
    .then(() -> {
        app.listen(Port, console.log(`listening on port :${Port}` .red.underline.bold));
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    })
```

---

You're not calling the function `connectDB`

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your Mongo Server and connect to your database before you attempt to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using a monorepo, one package initiates the server and another contains the mongoose models.

One of the packages had a different mongoose version on it's `package.json`'s dependencies.

The problem was fixed after making sure both packages had the same version of mongoose and then running `yarn` at the root of the monorepo to relink dependencies properly.

---

For anyone wondering, I'm able to use mongoose on two different packages in a monorepo since mongoose is basically a singleton class, meaning that it will usually try to use a pre-existing instance of mongoose wherever it is mentioned without initialization.

Having two versions of mongoose breaks this singleton functionality since (as far as Node is concerned) the instance on the server was created using a different mongoose package than the one on my models package.

---

**TL;DR** Make sure any packages in your monorepo depending on mongoose have the same version of mongoose in their respective `package.json` files.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered, however when I encountered with the same problem, the cause was very different. For some reason I put Mongodb connection URI inside quotes in config vars. Never do that. When I removed the quotes, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem at mongoose v "^6.3.4" and when I removed my IP from network access on sidebar on mongodb and added it again it worked

Answer (score 0):

> I faced this problem at mongoose v "^6.3.4" and when I removed my IP
> from network access on sidebar on mongodb and added it again it worked

This worked for me too. I removed my ip and selected "ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE" option on the network access page and it worked.

(I think it is safe: ["Allow access from anywhere" MongoDB Atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035947/allow-access-from-anywhere-mongodb-atlas))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33283363)