# Stuck in loading with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-web-server

I am trying to create a web-application with node.js, mongoose and MongoDB,
I am trying to load the web-page localhost:8800/api/auth/register which is stuck at loading since past 15 minutes.

VS Code Terminal return the following :

```
(node:2908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\Applications\chitter-chatter\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:2908) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:2908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\Applications\chitter-chatter\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:2908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
```

My Scripts are as following :

1. Index.js :

   ```
   const application = express();
   const mongoose = require("mongoose");
   const dotenv = require("dotenv");
   const helmet = require("helmet");
   const morgan = require("morgan");
   const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
   const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

   dotenv.config();

   mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, () => {
       console.log("connected to MongoDB")
   });

   // middleware 
   application.use(express.json());
   application.use(helmet());
   application.use(morgan("common"));

   application.use("/api/users", userRoute);
   application.use("/api/auth", authRoute);

   application.listen(8800, () => {
       console.log("backend server is running!")
   })
   ```
2. Auth.js :

   ```
   const User = require("../models/User");

   // REGISTER
   router.get("/register", async (req, res) => {
       const user = await new User ({
           username: "john",
           useremail: "john@gmail.com",
           userpswrd: "123456"
       })

       await user.save();
       res.send("oK")
   });

   module.exports = router
   ```

I am also using .env for MONGO VIA URL CONNECTION
Sorry for the bad writing apologies in advance also I am new to this so pls correct me! I know i have done a lot of mistakes,
Thanks for u're sincere time dedication and sympathy

Comment: `console.log("connected to MongoDB")` did this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseError: Operation \`users.findOne()\` buffering timed out after 10000ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66938905/mongooseerror-operation-users-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms)

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yes it logged connected to MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must make sure that you are connecting to the database without any error.
To do this, start listening on connect's callback function:

```js
try {
  // This configuration is better
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  }, err => {
    if (err) throw Error(err.message);

    console.log("connected to MongoDB");
    application.listen(8800, () => console.log("backend server is running!"));
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

I think you should make this operation in a try-catch statement like this:

```js
// REGISTER
router.get("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Create user in database
    const user = await User.create({
      username: "john",
      useremail: "john@gmail.com",
      userpswrd: "123456"
    });
    
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error });
    console.log(error);
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

Then you can see error's details, and server keeps running.
If you can't solve the problem just add a comment here I'll be back ASAP

Comment: I am pretty new so maybe making a very simple mistake but apparently the page loads but not how it should have been have a look : https://imgur.com/5mWzW7Q, also the data is not send to MongoDB that I have,

Comment: my new post is here which is further detailed sry for the inconvenience : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366495/express-web-page-not-loading-mongoose-throwing-error

Comment: At the photo it says password and email is required. I think you forgot User Schema properties. Just change `useremail` to `email` and `userpswrd` to `password` on `User.create` function

Comment: as I am working under some ppl they are requesting me to fix the code that they have choose that is : https://imgur.com/AsmuJWz
can u pls help me sort out with this, and yeah the earlier one did work, but still we have to work with this piece of code only

Comment: I've tried to run this code on my machine and it worked. Can you show me the `User` Schema

Comment: you don't need `await` keyword before `new User`. Saving user is an asynchronous event. Try a longer password

Comment: still no success ig an Unhadled Promise Rejection

Comment: Add `required: false` to non-required fields.

Comment: not working yet : updated schema here : https://imgur.com/zSoLnXD

Comment: Why you don't use try-catch and see the error, and did you try a longer password like "password"?

Comment: sorry but I can't find a solution for this. Maybe this can work `User.create({username: "john", email: "john@gmail.com", password: "password"})`

Answer (score 0):

check your router or wifi if you are using to run mongoose
try with your mobile internet

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).